# Funnel chart slice opacity in amCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

How can I set the opacity of the slices in `AmFunnelChart`? In the documentation there are many alpha fields, but not one for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make all the slices of the same opacity, set chart.alpha = 0.5;
To set a custom alpha for a slice, set chart.alphaField = "alpha"; and then add alpha field in data provider, with values you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I saw the 'alphaField' but I don't wanted to set in the data provider. The 'alpha' field works, but in the documentation I can't find this property, even in the inherited ones.

Comment: I mean I set chart.alpha = [number]. But that config option is not in the doc.

Comment: Indeed - fixed that, sorry.